# Ran "install homebrew" but "brew help shellenv" says "command not found: brew"

Tags: terminal, install, homebrew

I'm using a macOS Ventura.  It gave me a novel-length of text, which I assume confirmed installation of Homebrew when I typed "install homebrew".  Usually, that's what happens on the terminal, right?

It also can't find the directory, but I don't know if I can be bothered to search for that.  I'm just on vacation, and was hoping to learn how to code on this new MacBook I bought.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you specify the task that you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

## Installing Homebrew

Homebrew is installed using the instructions on the official site https://brew.sh.
The current installation process requires running this command in Terminal.app:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

[Alternative methods](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation) for installing Homebrew are also available.